# array request returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios, get

I send an array of Id s to this function:

```js
exports.findUsersById = (req, res) => {
  const ids = [req.params.id];
  ids.map((obj) => {
    User.find({
      _id: obj.id
    }, 'email', (err, user) => {

      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: err
        });
        return;
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: 'User Not found.'
        });
      }
      ret = [user]
      res.json([...ret, ret])
    });
  })
};
```

And i get back an empty array.What am I doing wrong?

it returns in postman:

```
[
  [],
  [
    []
  ]
]
```

update

I have the table:

```
User[_id(generated autimatically by mongo),name,email]
```

```js
Const mongoose =require("mongoose");

const User=mongoose.model(
    "User",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        email: String,
        ],
    })
)

module.exports=User;
```

I also have an array `dataObj.usersId` that looks like this:

```
['648395e2399eaef99a15ef57', '648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7', '648705e0c0a0395aa659251c']
0: "648395e2399eaef99a15ef57"
1: "648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7"
2: "648705e0c0a0395aa659251c"
length: 3
```

and here is in react the calling of the request: please ignore the first get and `iti.map`, it works perfectly but I wanted to show you all the code,just pretend that I send the array from above in `dataObj.usersId`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  iti.map((dataObj) => {
    return (
      axios
      .all([
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/cities/id/${dataObj.cityId}`),
        axios.get(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/allusersId/${dataObj.usersId}`
        ),
      ])

      .then(
        axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
          //   setCityName({ cityN: res1.data.name, cityC: res1.data.country });

          setUsersName(res2.data);
          console.log(res2.data);
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    );
  });
}, [iti]);
```

The console log shows this:

```
{data: Array(2), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
dashboard.tsx:64 (2) 
[Array(0), Array(1)]
```

But the arrays are empty

An example of user

```json
 {
   "_id": "6496058e19fdbb9e2d83a5eb",
   "name": "Georgiana",
   "email": "geo@itinero.com"
 }
```

And req.params.id:

```
['648395e2399eaef99a15ef57', '648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7', '648705e0c0a0395aa659251c']
```

Comment: Did you test your API with postman make sure it working. Cause seem like question is relate to axios but code provide is backend once

Comment: sorry, i wanted to put another question an I didn't saw axios. This node code is the problem for sure.

Comment: i have updated the question with what it returns in postman

Comment: Can you try to debug if query(value of user) is return any result, What is your database and what you use for query like : Sequelize, Mongoose , ... I can see some problem here but before I make a answer I would like to know more

Comment: Sure,it returns an empty array...

Comment: Is your User Table (Collection) have data. obj.id is valid when query?. Can you also provide into question how req.params.id , your database example record

Comment: i updated the questions. yes,the database is in mongodb

Comment: I may need actual value of `req.params.id` and some example record of User Collection

Comment: I updated it, sorry for the misunderstanding I am kinda new to coding. I hope I send the right infos this time

Comment: @HellCatVN do you know how to solve this? :( it s really bugging me for a long time and it is for my thesis

Comment: I don't see `req.params.id` match `User` _id for example maybe that why query return null :D you should make your query return value first. There is  a lot of error with you code as I can see